# Javascript Bookmarklets with Quotes

Tags: javascript, html, quotes, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I have had a problem with making javascript bookmarklets where the code inside contains both `""` quotes and `''` quotes.  Say for example, my code was as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Temporary HTML Doc</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:(function(){var a='something';var d='something_else'}());">Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would then proceed to open up the HTML file and drag the link to the bookmarks bar.  But, since the code has `""` and `''` quotes, whether or not I write the link as

```
<a href='javascript:(function(){var a="something";var d='something_else'}());">
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var a="something";var d='something_else'}());">
```

, it is still cut off, and the link becomes useless.

So, how can I include code that requires `""` and `''` quotes to work?
This example isn't my actual code, but it should hold for this problem.

[Wikipedia's page on Bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include a `"` character in an attribute value delimited by `"` characters, you would normally represent it as an entity: `&quot;`

However, since this is a URL, you should encode it for the URL first: `%22`

See a [live demo](http://jsbin.com/umoyoy/1/edit).

Comment: Hmm good call, I don't know why I swear I've used escaping in the past. The syntax highlighting didn't look right on SO either :(

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!  I doubted that special characters would, but I guess I was wrong.  That is the &quot; worked.